# Form ID & Name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to retrieve the Form ID & Name in jQuery?

Comment: For which form? Any form? Do you already have a reference to the form? In which context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one form, you can do this :

```
var id = $("form").attr("id");
var text = $("form").attr("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do something like this:

```
jQuery("form").each(function(e){
   var formID = jQuery(this).attr("id"):
   var formName = jQuery(this).attr("name");
   var action = jQuery(this).attr("action");
   var method = jQuery(this).attr("method");
});
```

Comment: Why bother with `$(this).attr("id")` - you can just `var id = this.id, name = this.name, action = this.action, method = this.method;` and be done with it...  Using `.attr()` on `$( this )` is basically wasting like 4 function calls and a whole bunch of other random statements...  The only ones that make any sense to use `.attr()` on are ones that are mapped to other values like `class`, even then `this.className` is going to be faster...

Answer (score 0):

And without jQuery:

```
var f, forms = document.forms;
for (var i=0, iLen=forms.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  f = forms[i];
  alert('form name: ' + f.name + '\nform id: ' + f.id); 
}
```

Comment: You know, the non-jQuery solution is good for reference, but posting a non-jQuery solution to a question that specifically asks for jQuery seems less useful than posting a jQuery solution to a generic JavaScript problem